# Moving from CGI to mod_perl. Understanding my, our, local

Tags: perl, scope, mod-perl, mod-perl2

I've been using apache mod_cgi during some years. Now I am moving to mod_perl and I have found some problems, specially with subroutines. Until now I was never using `my`, `our` nor `local`; and the CGI scripts worked without problems. After reading documentation and even some previous questions posted here I understand more or less how `my`, `our` and `local` works. My concern is what information is going to be shared between the next requests (if I understand correctly, that's the main concern I must have while running mod_perl instead of mod_cgi).

- Is there any difference between using `our` in a scalar or just the scalar without declaring anything special such as `my`? Aren't both global?
- If I do not declare the scalar as private is going to be shared in the next request? Even in another request of a different perl script in the same server?
- How can I share the value of a scalar inside a subroutine to outside that subroutine but not outside the same file nor the same request?
- If I use a `my` in a scalar inside an `if` in the same level of the file or in the same subroutine, and after that I create another `if` where I use the same scalar; is that scalar shared between both `if` or each `if` means different blocks? What about `while` and `for`, are they different blocks for the previously declared as `my` scalar or that only works for subroutines and files?

Comment: Unless you specifically need to interface with the guts of Apache, if you just want to speed things up, consider skipping mod_perl and proceeding directly to [Plack](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack) and FastCGI.  mod_perl ties you to Apache, bloats the entire HTTP process and can leak memory.  Many Perl web frameworks seamlessly work with Plack.  However, it has similar issues with global vs lexical variables so your question remains relevant.

Comment: @Zillo: you've gone very quiet. Do either of these answers tell you what you need to know?

Comment: @Schwern I've tried to run FastCGI on Lighttpd but it was not easy to setup. I am using FastCGI for PHP on Lighttpd but seems to be  more complicated to install FastCGI to handle Perl scripts.

Comment: @Borodin Your answer was very good but still I have some doubts;

- If I declare a "my" variable at the file level that variable is also going to be already defined in any sublevel, I mean any block  (such as subroutines, if...) only inside that file and for that request? 

If I want to define a variable in a block (subroutine, while, for...), if I want to use it also outside that block but just in that file and only in that request, how I should proceed? I should undef that variable at the begining and then declare the variable as "our"? Should I use again undef at the end?

Comment: @Zillo Perl + fastcgi should be significantly simpler than PHP as Perl does not need to be compiled with fastcgi support like PHP does.  [Apache also has fastcgi support](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/).  At its most basic, change your programs from using CGI.pm to [CGI::Fast](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Fast) and deal with the variable scoping issues, as you already are for mod_perl.  Basically, mod_perl is total overkill if you just want to improve performance.

Answer (score 17):

*mod_perl* works by wrapping each Perl script in a subroutine called `handler` within a package based on the name and path of the script. Instead of starting a new process to run each script, this `handler` subroutine is called by one of a number of persistent Perl theads.

Ordinarily this knowledge would help a lot to understand the changes in environment from *mod_cgi*, but since you have never added `use strict` to your programs and become familiar with the workings of declared variables you have a lot of catching up to do!

The *mod_perl* environment has the potential for causing non-obvious security breaches, and you should start now to `use strict` on *every* script and declare *every* variable. `use Carp` will also help you to understand the error logs.

A variable name declared with `our` is a lexically-scoped synonym for a package variable of the same name that can be used without fully qualifying the name by including the package name. For instance, ordinarily a variable declared with `our $var` will provide access to the `$main::var` scalar (if there has been no preceding `package` declaration) without specifying `main::`. However, such variables that began life with a value of `undef` in *mod_cgi* will now retain their values from the previous execution of any given *mod_perl* thread, and for consistency it is safest to always initialise them at the point of declaration. Note also that the default package name is no longer `main` because of the wrapping that *mod_perl* does, so you can no longer access package variables using the `main::` prefix, and it is unwise to find the actual name of the package and explicitly use that because it will be a *very* long name and will change if you move or rename your script.

A `my` variable is one that exists independently of the package symbol table, and normally its lifetime is the run time of the enclosing file (for variables declared at file scope) or subroutine. They are safe in *mod_perl* if both declared and used at file scope of the script or entirely within one subroutine, but you can be stung if you mix scopes and declare a `my $global` at file scope and then try to use it in a subroutine. The reason for this isn't simple, but it is caused by *mod_perl* wrapping your script in a `handler` subroutine so you have nested subroutine declarations. The inner subroutine will tend to adopt only the first instantiation of `$global` and ignore any others created by later calls to `handler`. If you need a global variable you should declare it with `our` and initialise it in that declaration as described above.

A `local` variable is very like an `our` variable in that it forms a synonym to a package variable. However it temporarily saves the current value of that variable and provides a new copy for use until the end of the file or block scope. Because of its automatic creation and deletion within its scope it can be a useful alternative to a `my` variable in *mod_perl* scripts, particularly where you are using pointers to data structures like, say, an instance of the `CGI` class. Declaring `our $cgi = CGI->new` would correctly create the object but, because of *mod_perl's* persistence, would leave it in memory until the next execution of the thread deletes it to make room for another one.

As for your questions:

- Using a variable without declaring it either causes a compile-time error if `use strict` is in place as it should be. Otherwise it is a synonym for that variable in the current package namespace.
- Variables are either package variables or lexical variables; there is no way to declare a variable as *private* as such. Lexical variables (declared with `my`) will be created and destroyed with each execution of the script, unless you have created an invalid *closure* as described above by writing a subroutine that uses a variable declared at a wider scope, when the variable will be persistent but won't do what you want it to. A variable declared with `our` will retain its value across calls to the script, while one declared with `local` will be destroyed when the script terminates. Both `our` and `local` variables are package variables and all references to the same variable name refer to the same variable.
- To declare a variable that is consistently accessible everywhere within any one call of a script you can either use a `local` variable or an initialised `our` variable. At file scope `local $global` is largely equivalent to `our $global = undef` for *mod_perl* scripts. If you use an `our` variable to point to a data structure then remember to destroy it at the end of the script with `undef $global`.
- `my` variables are unique to, and visible within, the block in which they are declared, whether that is a block within an `if`, `while` or `for`, or even just a bare `{ ... }` block scope. Always use `my` variables for temporary work variables that are used only within a block and accessed from nowhere else.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** this is general information on Perl variable scoping only.  Please see Borodin's post for specific `mod_perl` issues.

Variables declared with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) are lexical.  In other words, they exist only within the current scope.  You should declare all of your variables with `my` by default; only do something else when you specifically want different functionality.

Using lexically-scoped variables is a basic part of good code design in (almost) any language. Putting `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in all of your scripts will require you to follow this good practice.

`our` is a way of declaring a global variable; the underlying result is very similar to using undeclared globals.  However, it has two differences:

1. You are explicitly stating that you want the variable to be global.  This is a good practice to follow, since use of global variables should be an exceptional case.  Because of this, you can create a global in this way even if you `use strict;`.
2. The variable declared with `our` will be accessible by the name you declare throughout all packages in the current scope.  An undeclared variable, by contrast, is only accessible by simple name within the current package.  Outside of that, you could only refer to it as `$package::variable`.

See [the documentation for `our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) for more details.

[`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) does not create a lexical variable; instead, it is a way to give a global variable a temporary value within the current scope.  It is mostly used with Perl's special built-in (punctuation) variables:

```
{
   local $/; #make the record separator undefined in this scope only.
   my $file = <FILE>; #read in an entire file at once.
}
```

You can go far simply by using `my` at all times for your variables and using `local` only for special cases like that shown above.

Comment: This takes no account of the very different environment imposed by *mod\_perl*

Comment: @Borodin, oops, that was an oversight.  I read the question as not understanding how basic scoping works in Perl, and forgot about the `mod_perl` part.

Comment: A useful explanation of general Perl variable categories nevertheless